# Restrict my website to one per one user without authentification - compare date in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, restriction

How can I restrict a page only one by one user without authentification and with a delay of 3min between the first and second user. If anyone have a clue or a solution ?

Here is what I try to do : 
A unique User land in my page and fill a form and as I want to pick him by making a User.last I need him to be uniq on my page (to not disturb the registration and to be sure that i'm picking the right user with the User.last) and to wait 3 min for the second user to access this page. 
Like I have 10 peoples trying to access my website, 1 in filling the form, the 9 others are standing in a queue and waiting to access to my page. 
Actualluy try to do this in Ruby on Rails.

My view with the field looks like this (need to allow only one by one user on this page) :

```
<div class="container">
<center><h1>New Connection </h1></center>
    <%= form_with model: @email, local: true do |form|%>
        <% if @email.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error explanation" class="alert alert-danger">
            <p>Erreur(s) : </p>
                <ul>
                    <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |message|%>
                        <li><%=message%></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag :email %> :
            <%= form.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block", value: "Se connecter" %>
        </div>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

My email controller :

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def new
    @email = Email.new
    sessions = ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.pluck(:updated_at)
#return an array like this : 
   [Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:27:03 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:27:09 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:27:42 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:31:33 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:36:21 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:42:02 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:42:02 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:42:03 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:42:03 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:42:04 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:42:04 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:44:47 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:44:47 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:46:24 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:49:10 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:49:38 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:50:54 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 13:50:54 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:03:42 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:07:11 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:07:11 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:07:12 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:07:12 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:36:39 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:36:48 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:36:57 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:42:02 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:42:03 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:44:16 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:52:46 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:52:47 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:52:47 UTC +00:00, Tue, 21 Jan 2020 14:54:48 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:09:47 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:09:48 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:06 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:07 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:16 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:17 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:17 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:29 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:39 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:12:40 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:13:07 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:13:07 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:13:08 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:15:34 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:22:38 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:25:28 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:25:29 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:25:29 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:29:24 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:15 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:16 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:16 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:17 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:17 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:18 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:18 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:36:30 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:40:30 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:40:30 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:41:14 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:25 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:26 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:27 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:37 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:37 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:38 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:48 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:48 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:50:49 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:57:58 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 08:57:59 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:29 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:29 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:30 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:39 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:39 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:40 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:49 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:49 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:04:50 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:13:21 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:17:48 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:20:03 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:27:54 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:27:54 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:28:04 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:28:05 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:35:42 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:35:43 UTC +00:00, Wed, 22 Jan 2020 09:35:58 UTC +00:00]
    #How can I say that if a session is in the same minute than the previous session, redirect the one last one to another url?
  end

  def create
    @email = Email.create(email_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if@email.persisted?
        format.html {redirect_to invoice_index_path, notice: 'Email Validated '}
      else
        format.html{render :new}
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:email, :id_user)
  end
end
```

EDIT :

As suggested in the comment part, I tried to use the session, I can access to the session made by rails with `request.session_options[:id]` but how can I count them ?

EDIT 2 :

As suggested by ARK in the comment section, I try to use the Session created by Rails, I edited my controller part . 
How can I say that if a session is in the same minute than the previous session, redirect the one last one to another url ?

Comment: Please post what your configuration and code is, also what code you've tried.

Comment: Edited my post but for the moment I tried nothing, I have no clue how to do it, looking for some solutions or help to find a way to do that !

Comment: This question is illogical. Unless you have some form of authorization like a cookie how are you going to know if its the same user?

Comment: Use Rails` session object to distinguish between users: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: Thanks @SeanHuber I tried with the session object but still stuck to count how many people are on the page. Just edited my post

Comment: @TheGame so you can do this about counting the sessions. The server can keep track from the sessions count. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24431590/10313894